# ServiceStack site cannot be run with Azure emulator

Tags: azure, servicestack

I have hello world webservice from here https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice and it runs as a website without any problem.

But if I add this website as Webrole to Cloud Solution and try to run it in Dev Fabric emulator I'm getting error:

```
[Fiddler] The socket connection to 127.0.0.1 failed. 
ErrorCode: 10061. 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:82
```

I guess this happens because of compute emulator setup. It accept requests on 127.0.0.1:8X and then redirect to IIS(or IIS express) on 127.255.0.0:8X. Probably in this scenario ServiceStack routing misbehave.

Any workaround available?